# Is this polynomial a subspace of space $P_n(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Set of all polynomials that have zero order 3 in point 2

If I take polynomial $P_4(x)=(x-2)^3(x-3)$ and Polynomial $P_4(x)=(x-2)^3(x-1)$ and the sum of these two polynomials is $P_4(x)=2(x-2)^4$. This shows it does not belong in the set, so it is not a subspace, is this ok?

Comment: It is irrelevant that $f(x)=(x-2)^3(x^2+2x+1)$ is not equal to zero when $x=0$ is plugged in.  Do not confuse what your space is and what your elements of your space are.  Your elements of your space are the functions themselves.  Your zero vector is the zero function.  Your space is $V=\{f~:~f(x)=(x-2)^3(c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\dots+c_{n-3}x^{n-3})\}$ which is indeed a subspace of $P_n=\{f~:~f(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\dots+c_nx^n\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz But the zero polynomial doesn't have a zero of any specific order at point 3, so is it in the space described by OP?

Comment: @coffeemath depending on how you define it, every value of $x$ is a root of infinite order, including $x=2$.  I interpret the question as being that $2$ is a root of order *at least* $3$.  If the question were about having $2$ as a root of order *exactly* $3$ (*and not more*), then it will not be a vector space (*as evidenced by the additive identity element, i.e. the zero function, not being an element of the space*)

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you

Comment: To reiterate what was said in comments above, it depends on your interpretation of the phrase "*set of all polynomials that have zero order 3 in point 2.*"  If you interpret that to mean that the function is of the form $f(x)=(x-2)^3g(x)$ where $g(2)\neq 0$, that is $2$ is a root of order $3$ but not more, then it will not be a subspace as shown by your example and the easier example of the zero function (*which would by necessity have to be the additive identity in your space*).  If you interpret it as $2$ is a root of order at least $3$, then it will be a vector space and $(x-2)^4$ is in it.

Comment: yes I understand what you say